# ESP32-C3 - undefined reference to `esp_ble_gap_start_advertising'

Tags: esp32, bluetooth, platformio

I have a Bluetooth project for an ESP32 devkit and want to compile it for an ESP32-C3. I use the newest ESP32 Arduino core as a component with esp-idf and the following configuration for `PlatformIO`:

```
[platformio]
src_dir = src
default_envs = debug

# Common build environment that is used for each of the tasks
[env]
platform = espressif32
framework = espidf

board = esp32-c3-devkitm-1

# 4 MB module version
board_upload.flash_size = 4MB
board_upload.maximum_size = 4194304
board_build.partitions = partitions.csv

# Settings for serial upload
upload_speed = 921600
upload_port = COM2

# Settings for serial console
monitor_speed = 115200
monitor_port = COM2
monitor_filters = esp32_exception_decoder

# Additional packages
platform_packages =

# Aditional build scripts for all environments to run before (`pre`) and after (`post`) the main build script
extra_scripts =

# Common build flags for all environments
build_flags =

lib_deps =
    bblanchon/ArduinoJson@^6.18.0

[env:debug]
build_type = debug

build_flags =
    ${env.build_flags}
    -D DEBUG
    -D APP_VERSION_POST='debug'

lib_deps =
    ${env.lib_deps}

extra_scripts =
    ${env.extra_scripts}

[env:release]
build_type = debug

build_flags =
    ${env.build_flags}
    -D RELEASE

lib_deps =
    ${env.lib_deps}

extra_scripts =
    ${env.extra_scripts}
```

I use the following toolchain:

```
 - framework-espidf @ 3.40401.0 (4.4.1)
 - tool-cmake @ 3.16.4
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.30300.0 (3.3.0)
 - tool-idf @ 1.0.1
 - tool-mconf @ 1.4060000.20190628 (406.0.0)
 - tool-ninja @ 1.9.0
 - toolchain-riscv32-esp @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch3
```

But I got the following error during the linking:

```
.platformio/packages/toolchain-riscv32-esp/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv32-esp-elf/8.4.0/../../../../riscv32-esp-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\arduino-esp32\libarduino-esp32.a(BLEAdvertising.o): in function `BLEAdvertising::start()':
components/arduino-esp32/libraries/BLE/src/BLEAdvertising.cpp:247: undefined reference to `esp_ble_gap_start_advertising'
.platformio/packages/toolchain-riscv32-esp/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv32-esp-elf/8.4.0/../../../../riscv32-esp-elf/bin/ld.exe: components/arduino-esp32/libraries/BLE/src/BLEAdvertising.cpp:214: undefined reference to `esp_ble_gap_config_adv_data'
.platformio/packages/toolchain-riscv32-esp/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv32-esp-elf/8.4.0/../../../../riscv32-esp-elf/bin/ld.exe: components/arduino-esp32/libraries/BLE/src/BLEAdvertising.cpp:225: undefined reference to `esp_ble_gap_config_adv_data'
```

**Update 1**

A verbose build outputs the following command before the error appears:

```
riscv32-esp-elf-g++ -o .pio\build\debug\firmware.elf -T memory.ld -u esp_app_desc -u pthread_include_pthread_impl -u pthread_include_pthread_cond_impl -u pthread_include_pthread_local_storage_impl -u pthread_include_pthread_rwlock_impl -u include_esp_phy_override -u start_app -T sections.ld 
-u __ubsan_include -T esp32c3.rom.ld -T esp32c3.rom.api.ld -T esp32c3.rom.libgcc.ld -T esp32c3.rom.newlib.ld -T esp32c3.rom.version.ld -T esp32c3.rom.newlib-time.ld -T esp32c3.rom.eco3.ld -u __assert_func -u vfs_include_syscalls_impl -T esp32c3.peripherals.ld -u app_main -u newlib_include_heap_impl -u newlib_include_syscalls_impl -u newlib_include_pthread_impl -u newlib_include_assert_impl -u __cxa_guard_dummy -u __cxx_fatal_exception --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,--Map=C:/Projects/firmware-loader/.pio/build/debug/Firmware-Loader.map -Wl,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--undefined=uxTopUsedPriority -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_Backtrace -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_DeleteException -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_FindEnclosingFunction -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_Find_FDE 
-Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_ForcedUnwind -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetCFA -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetDataRelBase -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetGR -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetIP -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetIPInfo -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetRegionStart -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_GetTextRelBase -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_RaiseException -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_Resume -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_SetEnableExceptionFdeSorting -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_SetGR -Wl,--wrap=_Unwind_SetIP -Wl,--wrap=__cxa_call_unexpected -Wl,--wrap=__deregister_frame_info -Wl,--wrap=__deregister_frame_info_bases -Wl,--wrap=__gxx_personality_v0 -Wl,--wrap=__register_frame -Wl,--wrap=__register_frame_info -Wl,--wrap=__register_frame_info_bases -Wl,--wrap=__register_frame_info_table -Wl,--wrap=__register_frame_info_table_bases -Wl,--wrap=__register_frame_table -fno-lto -fno-rtti -march=rv32imc -nostartfiles -Og -g2 -ggdb2 .pio\build\debug\src\Devices\JERRY\jerry.o .pio\build\debug\src\Devices\Memory\memory.o .pio\build\debug\src\Devices\TOM\I2CM.o .pio\build\debug\src\Devices\TOM\tom.o .pio\build\debug\src\Loader\loader.o .pio\build\debug\src\Version\version.o .pio\build\debug\src\main.o -L.pio\build\debug -LC:\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\bt\controller\lib_esp32c3_family\esp32c3 -LC:\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\esp_wifi\lib\esp32c3 -LC:\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\esp_phy\lib\esp32c3 -L.pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_system\ld -LC:\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\esp_rom\esp32c3\ld -LC:\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\esp_wifi\lib\esp32c3 -LC:\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\soc\esp32c3\ld -Wl,--start-group .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_ringbuf\libesp_ringbuf.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\asio\libasio.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\protobuf-c\libprotobuf-c.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_lcd\libesp_lcd.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\mdns\libmdns.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\protocomm\libprotocomm.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\cbor\libcbor.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\cmock\libcmock.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\unity\libunity.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\bt\libbt.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\coap\libcoap.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_adc_cal\libesp_adc_cal.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_hid\libesp_hid.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\wear_levelling\libwear_levelling.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_local_ctrl\libesp_local_ctrl.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_websocket_client\libesp_websocket_client.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\expat\libexpat.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\fatfs\libfatfs.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\freemodbus\libfreemodbus.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\spiffs\libspiffs.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\openssl\libopenssl.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\libsodium\liblibsodium.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\jsmn\libjsmn.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\mqtt\libmqtt.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\json\libjson.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\wifi_provisioning\libwifi_provisioning.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\arduino-esp32\libarduino-esp32.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\RAK3172\libRAK3172.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\app_trace\libapp_trace.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\app_update\libapp_update.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\bootloader_support\libbootloader_support.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\console\libconsole.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\cxx\libcxx.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\driver\libdriver.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\efuse\libefuse.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp-tls\libesp-tls.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_common\libesp_common.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_event\libesp_event.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_gdbstub\libesp_gdbstub.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_http_client\libesp_http_client.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_http_server\libesp_http_server.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_https_ota\libesp_https_ota.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_hw_support\libesp_hw_support.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_ipc\libesp_ipc.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_netif\libesp_netif.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_phy\libesp_phy.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_pm\libesp_pm.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_rom\libesp_rom.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_serial_slave_link\libesp_serial_slave_link.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_system\libesp_system.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_timer\libesp_timer.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\esp_wifi\libesp_wifi.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\espcoredump\libespcoredump.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\freertos\libfreertos.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\hal\libhal.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\heap\libheap.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\log\liblog.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\lwip\liblwip.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\mbedtls\libmbedtls.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\newlib\libnewlib.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\nghttp\libnghttp.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\nvs_flash\libnvs_flash.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\pthread\libpthread.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\riscv\libriscv.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\sdmmc\libsdmmc.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\soc\libsoc.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\spi_flash\libspi_flash.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\tcp_transport\libtcp_transport.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\tcpip_adapter\libtcpip_adapter.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\vfs\libvfs.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\wpa_supplicant\libwpa_supplicant.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\mbedtls\mbedtls\library\libmbedcrypto.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\mbedtls\mbedtls\library\libmbedtls.a .pio\build\debug\esp-idf\mbedtls\mbedtls\library\libmbedx509.a -lbtdm_app -lcoexist -lcore -lespnow -lmesh -lnet80211 -lpp -lsmartconfig -lwapi -lphy -lbtbb -lgcov -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lgcc -Wl,--end-group
```

**Update 2**

It looks like `libbt.a` isn´t linked. May this cause this issue? How can I fix it or where do I find the required part in the build system of pio?

Comment: Is there a way to see which components have been linked or tried to be linked in PlatformIO?

Comment: @NickS. please take a look at my updated question. I have inserted the last command output in verbose build.

Comment: CONFIG_BT_BLE_42_FEATURES_SUPPORTED=y

Answer (score -1):

I have had a very similar issue just now. In short, the solution was to rename library file from .c to .cpp

Extended explanation. My platformio.ini:

```
[env:esp32doit-devkit-v1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32doit-devkit-v1
framework = arduino
```

I am using third-party library which I build from source. This library is provided by two  "lib_name.c" and "lib_name.h" files, which I have put into a lib/lib_name/ directory according to Platformio [README](https://github.com/platformio/platform-ststm32/blob/develop/examples/arduino-blink/lib/README) file.

It was failing during linkage until I renamed "lib_name.c" to "lib_name.cpp", header file remained untouched.